# Trying to create Junit for my eclipse application

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I M trying to create a Junit for my eclipse application , when I have tried to run the test as Junit Plugin Junit-Plugin Test:

```
public class QFPROMGridTest {
  @Test public void test() {
    System.out.println("Testing HGFYGFYYT"); 
    assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

the following error is thrown,

```
 BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -version 3 -port 51827 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -classNames com.qualcomm.qti.fusemaster.junitTest.QFPROMGridTest -application org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -testpluginname com.qualcomm.qti.fusemaster.junitTest
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -version 3 -port 51827 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime -classNames com.qualcomm.qti.fusemaster.junitTest.QFPROMGridTest -application org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication -product org.eclipse.platform.ide -data /prj/iceng/qsip1/workspaces/c_hgarik/fusemaster_workspace_Jan19/../junit-workspace -dev file:/prj/iceng/qsip1/workspaces/c_hgarik/fusemaster_workspace_Jan19/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/pde-junit/dev.properties -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -consoleLog -testpluginname com.qualcomm.qti.fusemaster.junitTest

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-02-24 01:38:45.002
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:55)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:22)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:256)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.getApplication(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.junit.runtime.NonUIThreadTestApplication.start(NonUIThreadTestApplication.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: Could we see the actual test?

Comment: I am trying to print a assert true, 
public class QFPROMGridTest {
 @Test
 public void test() {
  System.out.println("Testing HGFYGFYYT");
  assertTrue(true);
 }

Comment: How exactly are you running the test? What steps do you perform?

Comment: The stack trace doesn't correspond to the test

Comment: You are running it as a junit plugin test rather than just a junit test. Is this intentional?

Comment: Right click on the project and run as Junit plugin test

Comment: Try right click > run as Junit test

Comment: Do a `Run As`=>`JUnit Test`. If it's not available on the project, do it on the class.

Comment: @Trengot yes i want to run it as a JunitPlugin Test

Answer (score 2):

This error means that the Eclipse Runtime cannot find the application that it was told to launch in the extension registry.

To find out what's wrong, first check the console output. There should be a line starting with `Framework arguments:` which contains `-testApplication org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench` (or another testApplication depending on your settings).

Now open the *Debug Configurations ...* dialog and first check the tab *Main*. There is an option *Run an application* which you can use to select the application to run, if the application you found in the console as described above is not the one you expected.

If the application is the one you wanted, go to the *Plug-Ins* tab and check if the following plug-ins are selected:

- org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime
- org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime
- org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime
- **org.eclipse.ui.ide.application**

If not, select those plugins and then add all required plug-ins using the *Add Required Plug-ins* button.

Next, click the *Validate Plug-ins* button and resolve all conflicts that are still there.

If the validation says "No problems were detected", click on "Debug" (or "Run") to launch you tests again. It should now work (at least, it did for me after originally getting the error above and following these steps ...)

**Note:** If you have selected to launch a product instead of an application in the launch configuration, the Framework arguments might contain `-product` instead of `-testApplication`. In this case you need to find out the application launched by the product and make sure that the defining plug-in of this application and all of its dependencies are selected for inclusion.